# Asterisks for numbers with a separate tester

Tags: java

I am working on a class project where I have to create a Java class that will display asterisks for numbers.

For example, 5 would be *****.

Now I know there are a lot of these online, but ours requires 2 files. The actual loop is done in the main Java file, but the main method is in the Java test file.

```
public class BarChart {

private int numberOfStars;

public BarChart(int numberOfStars) {
    this.numberOfStars = numberOfStars;
}

public void displayBar() {
    for(int counter = 1; counter < numberOfStars; counter++); {
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println(); //display a new line at the end of all stars
}
}
}
```

Test Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarChartTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //loop 5 times asking for number
    System.out.print("Eenter a number:");
    int numberOfStars = input.nextInt();
    BarChart barChart = new BarChart(numberOfStars);
    barChart.displayBar();
}
}
```

My thought was that the loop would run, increment the counter each time until the counter equaled the number of stars, but it never prints more than 1 star.

For this assignment, I can only use the for loop and `System.out.print`.

Updated.

Comment: You're setting `numberOfStars` to 0 in your constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
this.numberOfStars = numberOfStars = 0;
```

This is always setting numberOfStars to 0

Also, your loop should be < numberOfStars and not <= numberOfStars, otherwise you will get one more than expected.

Update:

```
for(int counter = 1; counter < numberOfStars; counter++); {
```

Should be

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < numberOfStars; counter++) {
```

Comment: Eek, maybe edit your original post?  How is it not working exactly?

Comment: It won't run the loop, any number returns only 1 star.

Comment: If it helps, I'm getting a compiler warning about the for statement being empty.

Comment: Yes, it helps :)   It's the semi colon at the end.  `counter++);`  Remove it.  Also, the counter should start at 0.  See my updated answer.